# Why does Spark not invoke reduceByKey when the Tuple2's key is the original object in mapToPair

Tags: apache-spark, mapreduce, spark-streaming

I have a JavaDStream as in JavaDStream sourceDStream for stream processing.

In mapToPair for this DStream, I use the input object as the key and value for Tuple2 as in

Case 1:

```
public Tuple2<SourceObject, SourceObject> call(SourceObject sourceObject)
    Tuple2<WidgetDetail, WidgetDetail> tuple2;
    tuple2 = new Tuple2<> (sourceObject, sourceObject);
    return tuple2;
}
```

where sourceObject also implements equals () because it is also used as the key in mapToPair and reduceByKey.

I also call cache on both sourceDStream and rdd to ensure that they are processed before reduceByKey as in

```
sourceDStream = sourceDStream.cache ();
rdd = sourceDStream.mapToPair ()
rdd = rdd.cache ();
reducedRdd = rdd.reduceByKey ();
reducedRdd.foreachRDD ();
reducedRdd.foreachPartition ();
```

However, Spark

1. When a sourceDStream's size is small, say 50 or less, Spark does not call SourceObject's equals, so in turn reduceByKey is not called at all.
   So the duplicate keys are not reduced / merged when foreachPartition is called.
2. Even when sourceDStream's size is larger say 100+, Spark only call SourceObject's equals for a small subset of objects, 
   even though there are more objects in sourceDStream with the same key. So reduceByKey is not called for the remaining many objects with the same key.

Both above conditions result in excessive number of objects with the same key that foreachPartition needs to process.

Yet when I use a wrapper object as a key for sourceObject as in the code below

Case 2:

```
public class SourceKey {
    private SourceObject sourceObject;

    public void setSourceObject (SourceObject sourceObject) {
      this.sourceObject = sourceObject;
    }

    public boolean equals (Object obj) {
      ...
    }
 }  

 public Tuple2<SourceKey, SourceKey> call(SourceObject sourceObject)
    Tuple2<WidgetDetail, WidgetDetail> tuple2;
    SourceKey sourceKey = new SourceKey ();
    sourceKey.setSourceObject(sourceObject);
    tuple2 = new Tuple2<> (sourceKey, sourceKey);
    return tuple2;
}
```

then Spark works as expected where it calls SourceKey's equals for all objects in sourceDStream. So reduceByKey is called for all objects with the same key.

For case 1, why does Spark skip calling SourceObject's equals when SourceObject is also used as the key / value in Tuple2 of mapToPair ?

How do you solve this issue and have Spark calls SourceObject's equals for all objects in sourceDStream, so that objects with the same keys are reduced ?

Thanks.

Michael,